# Toast: MMS cannot be sent/received when mobile data is disabled -- shows up at every boot in Moto G XT1033 running Lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: security, mobile-data, mms

Details: Moto G XT1033 with
Android Lollipop 5.0.2

Is there something wrong? Why would any app request this feature just exactly when I turn my cell phone on?

[image: IMG: Message]

<sub>(Click image to see its larger variant.)</sub>

Comment: have you installed an app from unknown sources on your phone??
if you have, then you should install an anti-spyware app to find if there is a spyware in your phone.

Answer (score -1):

This is normal.

What it's saying is "if you want to send/receive MMS, turn mobile/cellular data on".

I don't know how to disable this toast.